# What is the output of the first round of AES

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key, aes, plaintext

For AES with a 128 bit block length and a 128-bit key length, what is the output of the first round of AES if the plaintext consists of 128 0's and the first subkey also consists of 128 0’s?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

The key is expanded using a PNG so you'll not get all 0's, but the XOR of 0 and 0 is....0

The output first round is dependent on the key as the key K is given as input which is expanded into a number of keys k1, k2 to kn – known as round keys.

The message M is inputted (128 bit for AES) and a round function is applied, so key k1 and round value 1 is the output which then has key2 applied to it so it becomes round 2 and so on for 10 rounds in the case of AES.